# Android - Mulitple listeners on a single view with the ability to pass off events to other views

Tags: android, gallery, listener, scrollview, multiple-views

I have a Gallery that contains a ScrollView.  I can scroll through the text in the ScrollView with a vertical swipe as is standard.  However, I would like the ScrollView to also listen for horizontal swipes which would then move the Gallery left or right.  Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here is what I found.  You will need to use onInterceptTouchEvent().  You can read about it here:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html

Alternatively, you can do a search for onInterceptTouchEvent example to find several examples.